# Extract exactly Public key as "Decimal" in PEM format in python

Tags: python, encoding, openssl, public-key, pem

I am trying to reach exact point of in PEM public key's decimal format. Not in Pem.

First of all i get my PEM certificate with using

```
from socket import socket

import ssl
from OpenSSL import SSL
import string
import traceback
import json
import re

for i in file_content:
    final_list.append(i.strip())


file = open("SSL_out_put.json","w")
Temp_Priv_Key_list = [] 

counter = 1
for i in final_list[:4047]:
    print counter
    print i
    counter = counter + 1
    try:
        x = ssl.get_server_certificate((i, 443))
        Temp_Priv_Key_list.append({
            'counter' : counter,
            'i' : i,
            'x' : x
            })
        content = json.dumps(Temp_Priv_Key_list, indent=3)
        file.write(content)
        Temp_Priv_Key_list=[]
    except Exception , err:
        pass
        print Exception , err
file.close()
```

after that i used "from pyasn1_modules import pem, rfc2459"
to extract the publick key. This will give binary representation for the public key. after converting decimal i reilze that this is not i want to use. 
Note that in my experiance pyasc1 is not working correctly.

After lots of research i found this code in here to extract public key BUT still in PEM format.

```
from cryptography import x509
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend

with open("cert.pem", "rb") as f:
    cert = f.read()

cert = str(cert)

x509 = OpenSSL.crypto.load_certificate(OpenSSL.crypto.FILETYPE_PEM, cert)
key_data = (OpenSSL.crypto.dump_publickey(OpenSSL.crypto.FILETYPE_PEM,x509.get_pubkey()))
print key_data
```

Now i have my Publick key as Pem format still. After some other research i found this but only giving this output. Still Can t extract the publick key nither decimal nor binary format.

```
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
from base64 import b64decode
from Crypto.Util import asn1

with open("public_key.pem", "rb") as f:
   cert = f.read()

#print cert

keyDER = b64decode(cert)
keyPub = RSA.importKey(keyDER)

print keyPub}
```

this code  will give you the out put of 
<_RSAobj @0x7f65559da320 n(2048),e>

This is my first question. Sorry if i don t asking  proper. My brain is full of all kind of staff with bunch of trash encoding that right now can't understand. Can some one please help me out of this issue.

i found http://lapo.it/asn1js/ that i exactly need it but i can t use it in python. i may use selenium or scrapy to extract the data what i want. But this will really kill me. There should be a way those modules that i tried :

those modules that i tried on this subject :

```
from pyasn1_modules import pem, rfc2459
from pyasn1.codec.der import decoder
from cryptography import x509
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import serialization
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric import rsa
#import pem
import socket, ssl
import OpenSSL
```

Btw for who is encountiring this issue with me . pycrypto is not properly woring on windows (although i install VCPython2.7.msi "you will know what i mean if you ll try it")i switch it to virtual-ubuntu. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Python ssl lib is not powerfull for this issue. So i change the whole thing to OPENSSL on linux terminal.

```
timeout 3s openssl s_client -servername (site_name) -connect (site_name):443 -no_alt_chains
```

this will give you the the PEM what browser will give because of s_client support SNI.

```
openssl x509 -in outer.pem -text
```

whit this one you ll get the all peer of your PEM file. if want to you exactly get the Public key modulus that will give you it as hexadecimal.

```
openssl x509 -in outer.pem -modulus -noout
```

Alitle bit subprocess you can easly get the output files from terminal outputs and with alittle bit regex you will get the all you want. Ty openssl. I hope i can help somebody who read this.